# How to automatically select all items above the selected one & deselect all items below the deselected one flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, select, checkbox, deselect

I have a custom list view with selectable items. And I am trying to select all items automatically present above the one I selected. For Ex: Suppose there is 10 items in the list view and I selected 5th then it should select all the items available above 5th. i.e(1,2,3,4) and when I deselect 3rd item 1,2,3 items should deselected automatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically select all items above the selected one flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979103/how-to-automatically-select-all-items-above-the-selected-one-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

// Assume that you have a list of items called 'items' and the index of the
//In This method you parse the index which one you tap.

```
ontap(int index){

   for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        items[i].isSelected = true;
        }
   for (int i = (index + 1); i < item.length; i++) {
        items[i].isSelected = false;
        }
}
```