# How to automatically select all items above the selected one & deselect all items below the deselected one flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, select, checkbox, deselect

```
  for (var item in _data)
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: _data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: item.isChecked,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          for (var i = 0; i <= _data.indexOf(item); i++) {
            _data[i].isChecked = value!;
          }
        }
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: You have a ListView.builder inside a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically select all items above the selected one flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979103/how-to-automatically-select-all-items-above-the-selected-one-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question,

Try this,

```
setState(() {
 for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
   if(i <= index){
    _data[i].isChecked = true;
   } else {
    _data[i].isChecked = false;
   }
 }
```